# Call jar file method from JNI layer in Android

Tags: android, jar, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am trying to create a application with JNI interface in android.

Below is the jar file class:

```
package testjar;

public class JNICallInterface {
    public native String mymethod();
    public JNICallInterface() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public String getString(String sd) {
        return "Hello All, I am from JAR";
    }
    public void gotoJNI() {
        System.out.print(mymethod());
    }
}
```

below is my JNI file:

```
#include <jni.h>

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_testndk_HelloWorld_messageFromNativeCode(
        JNIEnv * env, jobject jObj) {
    return 10;

}
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_testndk_HelloWorld_textMessageFromNativeCode(
        JNIEnv * env, jobject jObj) {
    jclass clazz = (*env)->FindClass(env, "com/testndk/HelloWorld");
    jmethodID messageMe = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, clazz, "messageMe",
            "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");
    jstring jstr = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "This string comes from JNI");
    (*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, jObj, messageMe, jstr);
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env,
            "Hello all... I am from JNI method call");

}
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_testjar_JNICallInterface_mymethod(JNIEnv * env,
        jobject jObj) {
    jclass clazz1 = (*env)->FindClass(env, "testjar/JNICallInterface");
    jmethodID messageMe1 = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, clazz1, "getString", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");
    jstring string = (*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, jObj, messageMe1,"ada");
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env,string);
}
```

Below is the LauncherActivity:

```
package com.testndk;

import testjar.JNICallInterface;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class HelloWorld extends Activity {
    TextView txtHello;

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("HelloWorld");// (“HelloWorld”);
    }

    public native int messageFromNativeCode();

    public native String textMessageFromNativeCode();
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        txtHello = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtHello);
        //int i = messageFromNativeCode();
        String str = textMessageFromNativeCode();
        txtHello.setText(str);
        JNICallInterface in=new JNICallInterface();
        in.gotoJNI();
    }
    public void messageMe(String msg) {
        Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

When I try to invoke the jar method from the JNI layer, I am getting a "NoSuchMethod" exception.

Is it really possible to invoke the Jar file method from the JNI layer. Am I missing something here???

Please help!

P.S: I am new to JNI

Comment: Check for exception or NULL result from `FindClass` to confirm whether the class is being found. (Also, for an instance method, you can just use the much faster `GetObjectClass` function on the object.) Same thing on the `GetMethodID` call. Copy & paste the exception text into your question so we can see the failure message.

Comment: 11-24 10:27:46.200: A/art(7759): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI CallObjectMethod called with pending exception 'java.lang.NoSuchMethodError' thrown in java.lang.String testjar.JNICallInterface.mymethod():-2
11-24 10:27:46.200: A/art(7759): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]     in call to CallObjectMethod
11-24 10:27:46.200: A/art(7759): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]     from java.lang.String testjar.JNICallInterface.mymethod()
11-24 10:27:46.200: A/art(7759): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65] "main" prio=5 tid=1 Runnable

Comment: the above is the error logs provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you follow the advice from fadden then you can see that the problem is in the method specification. The method in the JNICallInterface is

```
public class JNICallInterface {
...
    public String getString(String sd) {
```

but the native code searches for

```
jmethodID messageMe1 = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, clazz1, "getString", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");
```

and that means method returning `void` whereas the existing method returns `String`.

Comment: Thanks Zaboj. now I changed to : jmethodID messageMe1 = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, clazz1, "getString", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
 jstring string = (*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, jObj, messageMe1,"ada");........................... But Still I am getting same error. Can you please help.....

Comment: The spec `(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;` should be used for the method `String getString(String s)`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks fadden and Zaboj :) I was able to call the method and print the statements by using correct signatures.

my jar method::

```
public String getString() {
        return "Hello All, I am from JAR";
    }
```

my JNI call::

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_testjar_JNICallInterface_mymethod(JNIEnv * env,
        jobject jObj) {
    __android_log_print(2, APPNAME, "inside my method");
    jclass clazz1 = (*env)->FindClass(env, "testjar/JNICallInterface");
    __android_log_print(2, APPNAME, "class init");
    jmethodID messageMe1 = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, clazz1, "getString", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
    __android_log_print(2, APPNAME, "found my method");
    jstring string =(jstring)(*env)->CallObjectMethod(env,jObj, messageMe1);
    __android_log_print(2, APPNAME, "called method");
    const char *name = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env,string,JNI_FALSE);
    __android_log_print(2, APPNAME, "got string from jar :: %s",name);
    return string;
}
```

This works perfectly fine. Included log statements for cross checking.